# Differences between CSS images and SVGs

Tags: html, css, performance, svg, difference

I was wondering if there are any differences between CSS images and SVGs on your website.

By CSS images I mean images created with `div`s in HTML and styled in CSS (like this: https://codepen.io/andrewrock/pen/jOEZxrY).

Yes, CSS images are more time consuming, but apart from that they're both animatable, you can use CSS variables on them, make them dynamic with JS, ...

So what are the differences of those 2? (Performance, Rendering, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are countless reasons why you should use a svg instead of a group of html elements:

- **Creation**

  There are hundreds of svg editors that allow in a simple way to realize a drawing or an icon. This is not the case for html. So drawing a building icon in full css would be really painful.
- **Sharing**

  The fact that it uses a **standardized** file such as svg, allows you to export your work to other tools and easily be exploited by someone else. Use tricky css rules to manipulate some `span` or `div` can be difficult for a newcomer to your project to understand.
- **User experience**

  On a website that use svg, you will able to open it on a new tab or to download it. Thats very comfortable for an user for exemple. If you use `html` an user will not be able to manipulate and thats can be really annoying
- **Performance**

  Because the svg is called most of the time a file you can compressed it on your server to gain more space and performance with some tools like [Appendix J](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/minimize.html)